# Using grep to identify incorrect titles

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have several hundred documents where each title is of the form:

```
# Some title here {.WORD}
```

I want to identify using `grep` every title that does not follow this standard. However, lines starting with only # should not be detected.

```
##                          | OK
# Lorem .tip}               | NOT OK
# LIPSUM {.tip              | NOT OK
### Lipsum {.hello word}    | OK 
# Title                     | NOT OK
######## Title {.challenge} | OK
```

I wrote the following regexp to solve this situation

```
^##* .*(?<!{.*})$
```

However the parser complains about "lookbehind assertion is not fixed length" How, can I fix the regex expression above to remedy this?

Comment: well there's always the KISS approach: `grep '^##* ' file | grep -v '{.*}$'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -vE '^#+( [ [:alpha:]]+ \{\.[ [:alpha:]]+\})?$' file
# Lorem .tip}
# LIPSUM {.tip
# Title
```

The extended regular expression matches "OK" lines.  With `-v` we ask to see the lines that does not match.

The pattern requires that the line starts with some number of `#` characters.  The rest of the line is optional, but if it exists, it has to start with a space, then contain a number of letters, possibly with spaces in-between and then a final space before `{`.  The part within `{` and `}` must start with a dot, and may the contain some number of letters and spaces.

Answer (score 1):

When using lookaheads/lookbehinds you cannot put any glob type of regex's within them, they can only be fixed length strings.

You can use PCRE facility of `grep` do this:

```
$ grep -vP "(?<=#)*\s*\w*\s*{.*}|^[#]+$" afile
# Lorem .tip}
# LIPSUM {.tip
# Title
```

#### How this works:

- `(?<=#)*` looks for at least 1 or more `#`
- `\s*\w*\s*` looks for a sequence of space + word + space - these are zero or more
- `{.*}` looks for `{` followed by at least 1 character and a closing `}`
- `|^[#]+$"` looks for a line that's just a `#` or more